# Should I use Prometheus for resource gathering?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, prometheus

I use Prometheus to gather k8s' resources.
The resource data pipeline is as follows:

```
k8s -> Prometheus -> Java app -> Elasticsearch -> (whghl) Java app
```

Here I have a question.
Why use Prometheus?

Wouldn't Prometheus not be necessary if it was stored in DB like mine?
Whether I use Elasticsearch or MongoDB, wouldn't I need Prometheus?

Answer (score 0):

It definitely depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve by using these tools. In general, the scope of usage is quite different.

Prometheus is specifically designed for metrics collection, system monitoring and creating alerts based on those metrics. That's why it is the better choice if it is primarily required to pull metrics from services and run alerts on them.

Elasticsearch in its turn is a system with wider scope, as it is used to store and search all data types, perform different types of analytics of this data - and mostly it is used as log analysis system. But it also can be configured for monitoring, though it is not particularly made for it, unlike Prometheus.

Both tools are good to use, but Prometheus provides more simplicity in setting up monitoring for Kubernetes.